# default_random_engine seed makes c++ interpret variable as a function

Tags: c++, class, random, seed

I'm trying to make random numbers inside a class with this code:

```
#pragma once
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    default_random_engine engine(time(0));
};
```

Whenever I try to seed the default_random_engine, VS says that I haven't defined the function "engine". Even though the same code, outside the class, works just fine. If I don´t use a seed it says there's no mistake.

Note: I'm using a separate file for this class and this declaration is inside A.h but the same problem happens in the main function.

Comment: Use `{}`: `default_random_engine engine{time(0)};`

Comment: Or... `std::default_random_engine engine{ std::random_device{}() };`

Comment: it looks like is the same problem with the compiler interpreting it as a function, but it doesn't say how to fix it. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Thank you I'll try it

Comment: `()` is not accepted in member initialization to avoid Most vexing parse.

Comment: using { } works! Thank you